# Create nested mapped type

Tags: typescript

I have two types like this:

```
type ContactPerson = {
  firstName: string
  lastName: string
}
```

```
type Customer = {
  companyName: string
  contactPerson: ContactPerson
}
```

I need to map this type in a generic way to

```
type Result = {
  companyName: boolean[]
  contactPerson: {
    firstName: boolean[]
    lastName: boolean[]
  }
}
```

I can map the root level, but how do I handle the nested properties?

```
type BooleanResult<T> = {
  [Prop in keyof T]: boolean[]
}
```

Comment: ! You updated your question with the solution and now you're asking a new question? Maybe you should just post your own answer and then open a new question about the new thing instead of changing the scope of this.

Comment: [Here](https://tsplay.dev/N7g44N) is one way to make the compiler evaluate the type more eagerly, but I'm not going to work on an answer until this question evolves into its final form.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks this did the trick. As suggested, I've created a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69437971/get-type-of-nested-conditional-mapped-type-correcty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it this way:

```
type BooleanResult<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends object ? BooleanResult<T[K]> : boolean[]
}
```

It works as expected but the type info shows this:

```
type Result = {
    companyName: boolean[];
    contactPerson: BooleanResult<{
        firstName: string;
        lastName: string;
        email: string;
    }>;
}
```

Comment: Why does this work?