# Get type of nested conditional mapped type correcty

Tags: typescript

I have a type like this:

```
type BooleanResult<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends object ? BooleanResult<T[K]> : boolean[]
}
```

Having these two types:

```
type ContactPerson = {
  firstName: string
  lastName: string
}
```

```
type Customer = {
  companyName: string
  contactPerson: ContactPerson
}
```

When creating a type from it like this:

```
type Result = BooleanResult<Customer>
```

it works as expected but the type info shows this:

```
type Result = {
    companyName: boolean[];
    contactPerson: BooleanResult<{
        firstName: string;
        lastName: string;
        email: string;
    }>;
}
```

What do I need to change to reflect correct information like this

```
type Result = {
    companyName: boolean[];
    contactPerson: {
        firstName: boolean[];
        lastName: boolean[];
        email: boolean[];
    };
}
```

Comment: What typescript version are you using?

Comment: @smac89 I'm using version `4.4.3`

Comment: What you are attempting works in that version. See [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQg9nANhAhgOwEoQM4FdHAA8AKgHxQC8UA3gFBRQDaA0lAJZpQDWEIcAZlGIBdAFxCWwqBAAewCGgAm2KHABGAKwgBjYFAD8sBMnRY8BEpPLi1x1GkbDaAX1q1QkKAGE4aYCl0ABQgAJ2xfShp6KH42MOAAORQAWwhxbGAQjgBzaMQUDKTU9MycgBpoiGSUNkQSrLRsitd3cGgvXAy4VJDIugZtbrB0ECK0qAyG3IHffyDQ8LRxHz8A4GCw3xc3D2gzfD0qeCR7fYsOrp7SN0G0DJiEcTPDqIYZ5OG0UZTxxn4URDYCDCCpvKC3ObrBa+cT9MFvfKFH7iRiZXDA0HwhixeJjFH-QEY6JYqo1OpMNHA4lQVzOIA)

Comment: @smac89 yes, it works. It's just the preview shown by the compiler is not completely up to date.

Comment: That sounds like an IDE issue. You should raise an issue with the respective IDE, or possibly find what language server is used to provide type inference for the IDE and raise the issue there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One trick that often works to force the compiler to eagerly evaluate a type is to use [conditional type inference with `infer`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) to "copy" the type in question to a new type parameter, and then use the copy:

```
type BooleanResult<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends object ? BooleanResult<T[K]> : boolean[]
} extends infer O ? O : never
```

For your example, this results in:

```
type Result = BooleanResult<Customer>
/* type Result = {
    companyName: boolean[];
    contactPerson: {
        firstName: boolean[];
        lastName: boolean[];
    };
} */
```

as desired.

---

Other "no-op" tricks that seem to have the same effect:

- a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) with [the `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type):

  ```
  type BooleanResult<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends object ? BooleanResult<T[K]> : boolean[]
  } | never
  ```
- an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) with [the `unknown` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#unknown):

  ```
  type BooleanResult<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends object ? BooleanResult<T[K]> : boolean[]
  } & unknown
  ```

... (more later?)

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.3#code/FAFwngDgpgBAwgewHYgIYGMQAUoCcDOyMAvDAN7AxUwBmAlgSAHKoC2UAXDPiLnUgHNK1ADaoeLdlx59BwAL7BQkWHACuPBO1wlywqui0RUSMJM7de-IdRiGUGbHkJIuiB5hwFkCpUjZQ+MboqsgAJnQgdMioIgCSSDR4evow4NAwAEIICCJQJgBKgWoiIAA8ACoAfLoUtrYA2gDSMPwwANZQYAg0MBUAulwVzf0wUAAeIFBIYfgwCABGAFZQmDAA-Fk5eYXFpZUjNVwL2-lIDf2p8mOT07OtickA8hswL1xIUABueEqp6bAivgSiBdNlcmcgSCyupNNoqqkAPQAKjSKhgUNKtVStkMrGMpnMx1OJguAG4cdR7GhPM5kFw6vUmfRGESYCcIaT+hSmUyxBIAsTOeduZSqPIedRrsjEUpFMB-OwghhYABVJDRJBMb7JCj-dHgnZITHlarY3kwZoPDpdHp9QZ9EY3KYzOaLFZrTaGyF7U2HGBCo0XK4wAA+ME+P1wf1sAIxvrBJONvphGhAWjwCNsKLRGRN5t5eIJZkF7KT5LFdmQNKc3lcegtthZAqkZeFFcbonEzFLHKDootEpDMrlfz8AWVIRgCSmBFWIHV7SQCAA7kgUrGDUmTZUaqRGUyrW1Ot1egMhk6Ji77u7569vbtgfthk1+kc2-2QwAyGBqJBL1ckBjag43zUgH2TJ9ylhdN4SRVFQITfdKyLEwS1bPszg7Qtq0cLwXAZSsmwYFsLEwrlJU7fkeww8sB15IdbGlWUFCAA)

Comment: Thanks, actually I had to use the `... | never` version because my final version needs to make the mapped type properties optional `[K in keyof T]?:`

Comment: Can you elaborate on why optional properties has an effect on which version you use?  [I don't see that it matters](https://tsplay.dev/mMREbW), at least with your example code.

Comment: When creating an empty object like this `const result: Result = {}`, I get `Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Validation3BooleanResult<T>'.ts(2322)`. But this only seems to happen in my code, not in your playground.

Comment: Presumably it has to do with deferred unresolved generics (your `T` is not yet specified) and not optional properties.